# How to unload bootstrap, when you change the microfrontend?

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, bootstrap-4

I have a problem, when our team is using react and bootstrap, and other modules which have different technology, they're using tailwind, so when the link from our micro frontend changed to theirs, our Bootstrap styles still persist, and because tailwind and bootstrap have many some class names but with different options we have now issues with this in our styling. So this bootstrap _utilities.scss going from the webpack, for some reason, even if I exclude node_modules, maybe somebody is faced with this and knows the solution to the issue?
This is the path for this scss when highlight it: webpack://./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_utilities.scss
P
[image]

My webpack config for excluding nodu_modules:

> module: {
> rules: [
> {
> test: /.(js|ts|tsx)$/,
> exclude: /node_modules/,
> use: {
> loader: 'ts-loader',
> },
> },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the solution, first crate separate bootstrap.scss do an import of bootstrap.css inside this .scss file (in my case I need just grid from bootstrap):

```
@import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css';
```

These settings should be in webpack.configuration.js for sass or scss files:

```
 return merge(filteredConfig, {
    entry: './src/moduleEntry.tsx',
    plugins: [
      new ESLintPlugin({ extensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx'] }),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: `${moduleName}.css`,
      }),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
        {
          test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
          use: [
            // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
            !isProduction ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            // Translates CSS into CommonJS
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                modules: {
                  auto: true,
                  localIdentName: '[local]-[hash:base64:5]',
                },
              },
            },
            // Compiles Sass to CSS
            'sass-loader',
          ],
        },
...]
}
```

These changes will take your .scss file in production mode, merge it into a single.css file, and place this CSS from Bootstrap into this style.css for your exact module.